# Conditional loop using if statement

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm learning some basic javascript, and would like to learn how to return to the beginning of a method when certain conditions are met.

In this scenario, the user must enter a character in the prompt in order to proceed to the statment "The character you typed was" string. I would like to implement a loop to send the program back to the start of the method if nothing is entered. I have the following, so far:

```
<script class="promptwindow">            
        var x
        x = prompt("Please type a character in the box and click OK", "")

        if (x = null)
            {****}

        document.write("The character you typed was ", x)    
</script>
```

I'm unsure what to use in the **** bracket, I need something similar to `goto`.

Edit: Yep, should have been `==`. I'll leave the mistake there so that the comments make sense.

Comment: ```class="promptwindow"``` in ```script``` tag?

Comment: no -> `if (x = null)`  yes -> `if (x == null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go back to the beginning of your function, just call it again:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   ( function myFunction() {
        var x;
        x = prompt("Please type a character in the box and click OK", "")
        if (x === null)
            myFunction();
        document.write("The character you typed was ", x);
    })();
</script>
```

Be carreful to the `document.write()`'s position, when `x` will not be null anymore, all stacked `document.write("The character you typed was ", x);` will be executed

You can also use a loop...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var x = null;
        while(x === null || x === ""){
            x = prompt("Please type a character in the box and click OK", "")
        }
        document.write("The character you typed was ", x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I was hoping for something like this, +1.

Comment: Erm... actually, this now does nothing at all. It's now just a blank page.

Comment: @Wolfish Of course you have to call the function once to start it

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I'm using `OnLoad` in the `<body>` tag, but the loop doesn't seem to work. Edit: made the self-invocation work, but the loop is still broken.

Comment: Actually `prompts` returns an empty string instead of `null`, the loop's condition should be updated

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type = "text/JavaScript">
    function UserInput(_callback_)
    {
        var value = "";
        do
        {
            value = prompt("Please type a sentence in the box and click OK", "");
        }
        while(value === "");

        _callback_(value);
    }

    UserInput(function(text){
        document.write("The sentence you typed was { " + text + " }");
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dqda8Lgk/

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: This is a little more advanced, I'll be looking at callbacks later on today. I appreciate the snippet though, +1